# How to sort by 2 different columns?

Tags: sorting, vim, multiple-columns

I want to sort a text by 2 different columns:

```
aaa5aaaaa
aaa3azaba
aaa4aaaaa
aaa3abaza
```

The 1st sort must be only at column 4 and if there are equal numbers p.e. in above example '3' the 2nd sort must be at column 8 and if there are still the same characters the next column must be 9 etc.

I thought that this would be the solution:

```
%sort i /\%4v\|\%8v/
```

but it doesn't work.

Output:

```
aaa3abaza
aaa3azaba
aaa4aaaaa
aaa5aaaaa
```

Expected Output:

```
aaa3azaba
aaa3abaza
aaa4aaaaa
aaa5aaaaa
```

Comment: sort it by 8th column and then sort again by 4th column :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what's wrong with your attempt:

- The `/pattern/` argument to the built-in `:sort` specifies the text to **skip**; you're apparently attempting to *match* certain columns.
- The `\%v` atom is *zero-width*, so you'd probably need to append a `.` to make it match the character (if this would work despite the first point).
- I don't think that there's a way to specify multiple search keys (i.e. your character positions 4 and 8) with the built-in `:sort` at all.

If you have *GNU sort* installed (i.e. Linux system or via Cygwin), you can use this external command:

```
:%!sort -k1.4,1.4 -k1.8,1.8
```

This specifies the two character columns 4 and 8 as offsets of the first field (`1.`) as sort keys.

Comment: Very nice! Yes I have GNU Sort installed. Do you know where to find more info on the offset value? p.e. what would be the offset value if I want to sort only on column 4 and column 8 and after (>=8)? I haven't found out as well how to sort one column p.e. col. 4 normally and column 8 reverse...

Comment: For >= a column, just leave off the second `,1.x` value; append `r` for reverse sort. [man sort](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) has you covered with all the information, and there are several questions around `sort` here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

this line:

```
sor /\%7v/|sor n /\%3v/
```

works for your example.

it does two sorting, first sort by col8, then sort by col4 (as number).

Comment: Note that this depends on `:sort` being a stable sort, and 'the details about sorting depend on the library function used.  There is no guarantee that sorting is "stable" or obeys the current locale.' (from `:h :sort`)